# javascript changing the default hardcoded value using command line

Tags: node.js, nodes

i want to add a function wherein when the user type in the commandline 'node filename.js option' it will ask the user to enter the new default value for the batchSize, startDate, endDate, frequencyUpload and when i run again the 'node filename.js' the newly inputed value will now be the default value.

I try this but it's not working

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const axios = require('axios');
const ms = require('ms');
const { format } = require('date-fns');

const config = {
    user: 'leo',
    password: 'Leocoronel24',
    server: '192.168.13.33',
    database: 'TKMANAGER',
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
};

const logs = [];
let intervalId;

// create a function to connect to the database and retrieve data
async function getData(batchSize, startDate, endDate) {
  // your existing code for getting data goes here
  try {
    // connect to the database
    await sql.connect(config);
    console.log('Connected to the database');

    const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

    


    // create a request object to retrieve data
    let sqlquery = `SELECT TOP ${batchSize} Employeenum, DTRDATE, COMPANYID, FUNCTIONKEY, 
    CASE WHEN FunctionKey = 1 THEN DTRTIMEIN ELSE DTRTIMEOUT END AS TRANSACTIONTIME,
    [NAME], SeqID
    FROM viewDTR1 
    WHERE DTRDATE BETWEEN '${formattedStartDate}' AND '${formattedEndDate}'`;
    //WHERE DTRDATE BETWEEN '2023-03-01' AND '2023-03-15'`;

    const result = await sql.query(sqlquery);

    let entries = result.recordset.map(row => ({
        dtrdate: row.DTRDATE,
        datetime: row.TRANSACTIONTIME,
        type: String(row.FUNCTIONKEY),
        location: row.NAME,
        company: row.COMPANYID,
        cardno: row.Employeenum,
        ipaddress: '192.168.1.1'
    }));

    let data = { entries: entries };

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    //logs.push(`Retrieved ${entries.length} entries at ${transactionTime()}.`);
    //logs.push(`Retrieved data: ${JSON.stringify(entries, null, 4)}\n at ${transactionTime()}.`);
    logs.push(`Retrieved data: ${JSON.stringify(entries)}\n at ${transactionTime()}.`);

    const response = await axios.post('http://dev.megaworldcorp.com:8000/tkserve/uptk.php', {          
        entries
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        method: 'POST'
    });

    console.log(response.data);

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
} finally {
    sql.close();
    console.log('Disconnected from the database');
}
}


function isValidDate(dateString) {
  const regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if(!regex.test(dateString)) {
        return false;
    }
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function transactionTime() {
 
  const now = new Date();
  return format(now, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
}

function startDataRetrieval(batchSize, uploadFrequency, startDate, endDate) {
  const transactionStartTime = transactionTime();
  console.log(`Transaction started at ${transactionStartTime}`);
  getData(batchSize, startDate, endDate);
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    getData(batchSize, startDate, endDate);
  }, ms(uploadFrequency));
}

function stopDataRetrieval() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

const defaults = {
  batchSize: 10,
  startDate: '2023-01-01',
  endDate: '2023-01-31',
  uploadFrequency: '10s'
};

// parse command-line arguments for batch size, start date, end date, and upload frequency
let args = process.argv.slice(2);
if(args[0] === 'option'){
  function promptForNewValues() {
    rl.question('Enter new default batchSize: ', (batchSize) => {
      rl.question('Enter new default startDate (yyyy-mm-dd): ', (startDate) => {
        rl.question('Enter new default endDate (yyyy-mm-dd): ', (endDate) => {
          rl.question('Enter new default uploadFrequency (e.g. 10s, 1m, 1h): ', (uploadFrequency) => {
            // update defaults here
            defaults.batchSize = batchSize;
            defaults.startDate = startDate;
            defaults.endDate = endDate;
            defaults.uploadFrequency = uploadFrequency;
            console.log('Defaults updated.');
            rl.close();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
else{
  let batchSize = args[0] || defaults.batchSize;
let startDate = args[1] || defaults.startDate;
let endDate = args[2] || defaults.endDate;
let uploadFrequency = args[3] || defaults.uploadFrequency;

if (!isValidDate(startDate) || !isValidDate(endDate)) {
  console.log('Invalid date format. Please enter dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.');
} else if (startDate === endDate) {
  console.log('Start date and end date should not be the same.');
} else {
  startDataRetrieval(batchSize, uploadFrequency, startDate, endDate);
}

}
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});






// allow user to stop data retrieval by pressing "s" or "S"
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
  if (data.toString().trim() === 'p' || data.toString().trim() === 'P') {
    stopDataRetrieval();
    console.log('Data retrieval stopped.');
    process.exit();
  } else if (data.toString().trim() === 'c' || data.toString().trim() === 'C') {
    promptForNewValues();
  }
});

console.log('Press "p" or "P" to stop data retrieval.');
console.log('Press "c" or "C" to update default values.');
```

Comment: I haven't read all the code in your question yet but generally what you need is some kind of persistence (file, DB, etc). If an argv is present, update the config. Otherwise, grab the value from persistence